# "Line up", "Hook up" and "Fix up"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Please tell me which choice below (or rather a better choice that I need to know) works better in my sentences **in informal English**:

> I got myself out on a limb. I need to clear my check by tomorrow. No matter how, I must ............ 2 million bucks by tomorrow.

**a) line up** [to prepare, organize, or arrange something] 
**b) hook up** [hook somebody up with something to help someone get something that they need or want] 
**c) fix up** [to arrange for someone to have something that they need]

For me, all three options work in this sense with the same meaning and informality degree.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "line up" seems like the best choice of the options given.

"Hook up" makes it sound like you're gathering the money for someone else, which sounds awkward without specifying who that is, e.g. "I need to hook up John with the million bucks I owe him"

"Fix up" sounds okay, but is probably less common.

Comment: Thank you @Cody and to which type of English does your analysis applicable? I mean AE or BE. Perhaps there are some serious differences in this case.

Comment: I'm American. "Fix up" sounds a bit British to me, but I'm not sure ;)